# Beats Studio 3 Wireless headphones spontaneously disconnecting only from MacBook

Tags: mac, audio, bluetooth, headphones

Sorry if this isn't the appropriate forum to ask this question. I have Beats Studio 3 Wireless headphones that I've been using seamlessly for years with my iPhone X (iOS 13.1), iPad Pro 10-inch (iPadOS 13.3), and MacBook Pro (macOS Catalina 10.5.2, Early 2015 retina model).
Recently, I tried switching the headphones from iPad to laptop and it wouldn't disconnect from the iPad and it wouldn't connect to the MacBook; switching to the iPhone however took a few seconds. I was able to temporarily get it to work on the MBP by non-stop clicking on the headphones in the Bluetooth menu but usually the connection would last for a few minutes before disconnecting automatically. I have many other bluetooth devices hooked up to the laptop which work perfectly: magic mouse, keyboard, AirPods, external speaker, and trackpad.

I've tried everything I could think of and read up about (disconnecting/reconnecting, power cycling, Beats Updater software, factory reset, some combination of holding buttons for 10 or 20 seconds) but no luck still.

Anyone have similar issues? Or know what to do? I can't tell if the issue is with the headphones or the laptop, since they both connect to other things without any problem. Would appreciate any advice, thanks!

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. It seems to be a serious bug in Catalina and there are apparently at least _hundreds_ of people with the exact same problem over on the Apple main support forums. With absolutely no meaningful acknowledgement by Apple support, of course.